# Spring boot email sending with attachment

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, email-attachments

```
Technology: Spring Boot
Hello Developers, Can sombody tell me what is wrong with my code?
Why i'm unable to send attachment in email?
Exception:
```

There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Failed to convert value of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile' to required type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile' to required type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

My jsp page

```
<pre>
<form:form modelAttribute="attachmentEmail" method="POST" action="/email-app/sendAttachmentEmail" cssClass="register-form"
id="register-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="fname"><i class="zmdi zmdi-account material-icons-name"></i></label>
    <form:input path="name" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" required="required" />
    <form:errors path="name" cssStyle="color:red;" cssClass="error" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="phone"><i class="zmdi zmdi-phone"></i></label>
    <form:input path="phone" name="phone" id="phone"  placeholder="Phone" required="required" />
    <form:errors path="phone" cssStyle="color:red;" cssClass="error" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="email"><i class="zmdi zmdi-email"></i></label>
    <form:input type="email" path="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required="required" />
    <form:errors path="email" cssStyle="color:red;" cssClass="error" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="subject"><i class="zmdi zmdi-account material-icons-name"></i></label>
    <form:input path="subject" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" required="required" />
    <form:errors path="subject" cssStyle="color:red;" cssClass="error" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">    
    <form:textarea path="comment" name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="Comment" rows="5" cols="35" required="required" />
    <form:errors path="comment" cssStyle="color:red;" cssClass="error" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="attachment"><i class="zmdi zmdi-file"></i></label>
    <form:input path="attachment" type="file" name="attachment"  id="attachment" required="required" />
    <form:errors path="attachment" cssStyle="color:red;" cssClass="error" />
</div>
<div class="form-group form-button">
    <input type="submit" id="signup" class="form-submit" value="Send" />
</div>
</form:form>
</pre>
```

My Contact.java & EmailController.java

```
<pre>
public class Contact {

@NotNull(message = "Name can't be blank.")
private String name;

@NotNull(message = "Name can't be blank.")
private String phone;

@NotNull(message = "Email can't be blank.")
private String email;

@NotNull(message = "Subject can't be blank.")
private String subject;

@NotNull(message = "Comment can't be blank.")
private String comment;

private CommonsMultipartFile attachment;
//getters
//setters
}
</pre>

My EmailController.java

<pre>
@RequestMapping(value ="/sendAttachmentEmail", consumes = "multipart/form-data", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView sendEmailWithAttachment(HttpServletRequest request, final @RequestParam("attachment") CommonsMultipartFile attachFile) throws MessagingException {
try {
ModelAndView mav =new ModelAndView("success");
log.info("Spring Boot - Sending Attachment Email...");
// reads form input
final String email = request.getParameter("mailTo");
final String phone = request.getParameter("phone");
final String name = request.getParameter("name");
final String subject = request.getParameter("subject");
final String comment = request.getParameter("comment");

    log.info(name+" "+phone+" "+email+" "+subject+" "+comment);

    if ((attachFile != null) && (attachFile.getSize() > 0) && (!attachFile.equals(""))) {
        log.info("FileName====="+attachFile.getOriginalFilename());
    } else {
        log.info("FileName====="+attachFile.getOriginalFilename()+" "+attachFile);
    }
    Contact contact = new Contact();
    contact.setName(name);
    contact.setPhone(phone);
    contact.setEmail(email);
    contact.setSubject(subject);
    contact.setComment(comment);

    mav.addObject("name", contact.getName());
    log.info("Sening Attachment Email...");
    emailService.sendAttachmentEmail(contact, attachFile);
    log.info("Done...");
    return mav;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage());
        return new ModelAndView("attachment-email");
    }
}
</pre>
```

My EmailServiceImpl.java

```
<pre>
@Override
public void sendAttachmentEmail(Contact contact, CommonsMultipartFile attachfile) throws MessagingException {     
emailSender.send(new MimeMessagePreparator() {
public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception {
MimeMessage message = emailSender.createMimeMessage();
MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true, "UTF-8"); // Enable the multipart flag!
String content = "Hi, <b>"+contact.getName()+"</b> Thank you for Contacting Us. PFB attachment.<br>";
helper.setSubject(contact.getSubject());
helper.setText(content+" <b>Comment:</b> "+ contact.getComment(), true);
helper.setTo(contact.getEmail());
helper.setFrom(env.getProperty("spring.mail.username"));

// Determine If There Is An File Upload. If Yes, Attach It To The Client Email              
if ((attachfile != null) && (attachfile.getSize() > 0) && (!attachfile.equals(""))) {
    System.out.println("\nAttachment Name?= " + attachfile.getOriginalFilename() + "\n");
    helper.addAttachment(attachfile.getOriginalFilename(), new InputStreamSource() {                   
        public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
            return attachfile.getInputStream();
        }
    });
} else {
    System.out.println("No Attachment Is Selected By The User. Sending Text Email.");
}
        }
    });
}
</pre>
```

After submitting the button i am getting above mentioned error, Kindly help.

Comment: Use `org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile` instead of CommonsMultipartFile in your controller method

Comment: Hello, as you suggusted i used org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile instead of CommonsMultipartFile in my controller method but now i am getting this error "Failed messages: javax.mail.SendFailedException: No recipient addresses", i cross checked my email address and it were correct now how to solve this error?

Comment: Check what is actually in `contact.getEmail()`... I'm assuming it must be blank?

Comment: Actually... instead of using `MimeMessage message = emailSender.createMimeMessage();`.. trying using the mimeMessage that is passed in the prepare method.... `MimeMessage mimeMessage`

Comment: No sir,i checked it in my console and it is printing a valid email address.

Comment: See last comment I made

Comment: Yeah, it works thanks a lot sir.....

Comment: No problem! 

Answer (score 0):

The essential is here: *Cannot convert value of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile' to required type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile': no matching editors or conversion strategy found*

By the other words try to change signature of your controller's method `sendEmailWithAtachment` on:

```
public ModelAndView sendEmailWithAttachment(HttpServletRequest request, final @RequestParam("attachment") StandardMultipartFile attachFile)
```

Comment: Hi,i am not getting StandardMultipartFile class in spring can you tell me in which package it is belong?

Comment: I found similar controller in one of my projects. It works. Signature looks like:  public @ResponseBody Response upload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, HttpServletRequest request)  . And MultipartFile is  org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile